# Another pronoun replacement question

Tags: pronouns

Consider the following sentence I wrote myself:

> Kumbhakarn then pierced Hanuman's chest with his spear due to which
> Hanuman was seriously injured.

If I replace 'Hanuman' with 'he', the sentence becomes:

> Kumbhakarn then pierced Hanuman's chest with his spear due to which
> he was seriously injured.

Which sentence is preferable?

I posted a similar question an hour ago, but this one has an additional conundrum: if I do the pronoun replacement, 'his' would refer to Kumbhakarn whereas 'he' would refer to Hanuman. Is this acceptable in English?

Comment: *...due to which he was seriously injured* isn't very natural. Consider replacing with something like *...seriously injuring him* or *...which seriously injured him*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily better, but another option: "...with his spear, seriously injuring _the latter_" ("the latter" indicates the person mentioned last).

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have two pronouns with different antecedents. In this case it should not be confusing because the person who is injured by a spear is usually not the person wielding the spear.